# Is it safe to read an int that is being concurrently incremented without synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, integer

I have thread A that only read the int, and thread B that only increment it.

I don't need thread A to be exactly up to date on the value, it can be 8 when it actually is 9, it's ok because it's a loop and he'll get to 9 at some point.

The problem is I have an array of fixed size, an int that stores the current index (last emplacement read by thread A) and another int that stores the "size" of the array. Both int start at 0 and every update thread A looks if the size int is bigger than the index int, if yes it catches up and read the new values.

I would like to know if I can avoid synchronization because I don't need exact accuracy.

Comment: Without synchronization the results are not specified. Practically I would expect you to get 8 or 9, in this case. But it could be anything. There's nothing in the C++ specification that prohibits you from getting, as a result, 42, -17 or the speed of light in a vacuum. The results could be anything.

Comment: And in more practical terms: think what will happen if that int is stored in a register on at least one of the sides. You better start with as much synchronization you need in order to be absolutely safe, and try to fine-tune it only if you're sure that's the bottleneck.

Comment: You definitely cannot avoid synchronization, but you can use std::atomic<int> which will be extremely fast for increments.  Under the hood there will be some form of [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetch-and-add](fetch and add), which is a very fast CPU-level atomic operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The behavior is undefined. At best, your "don't need exact accuracy" turns into "can tolerate nonsensical values".

Suppose that one thread has just incremented a value across a byte boundary. For example, going from 255 to 256 on a system with 8-bit bytes. Before the increment, the high byte has the value 0. After the increment the low byte has the value 0. Is reading a value of 0 here acceptable? Because that's what you could well see: a thread switch after writing the low byte and before writing the new byte would result in another thread seeing both bytes as zero.

**NOTE** this is a handwaving argument, intended to give you a feel for the kinds of problems that synchronization solves. It is not intended to suggest good practice. Good practice requires synchronization, regardless of what you might guess the result could be without it.

Comment: If a program has a data race its behivior is undefined. Undefined behavior goes well beyond the possibility of nonsensical data. [This lovely article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) talks a bit about why the outcome can be dramatically different from values just being a bit off.

Comment: The number is a 32/64 integer and doesn't go beyond 512, can it still produce nonsensical values?

Comment: @Percee -- read my last paragraph again, especially the last sentence. And read the article that Dietmar's comment links to.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to read an int that is being concurrently incremented without synchronisation

No, it's unsafe.

A race condition involves at least one writer thread. (If all threads are just reader threads then there is no race condition, and no locking is required).

In your case, you have two threads that are both writer threads (ie modifying a shared resource). So there is a race condition. And you need to implement locking to the shared resource (ie the counter) to be thread safe.

Comment: A race condition requires only one writer and one reader, not at least two writers.

Comment: Don't apologize to me. <g> You'll get down voted to death until you fix it or delete it.

Comment: @PeteBecker I don't care about the downvotes, not an issue. I'm reading Mat comment

Comment: Your answer is still inaccurate. There is only one writer in the question, and what is required is some form of synchronization, which does not necessarily involve locking.

Comment: @Mat I'd like to know an example of some form of synchronisation without locking

Comment: Look up `<atomic>`s. Some can be lock-free.